# Vue/Typescript/Amplify reset password issue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have just started working fro this startup and going through the code. Hope to find someone who is fluent with Amplify. The issue I am facing is that if you forgot your password and you press "forgot password" button - it should send you the code to your email to renew the password.

When I try it first time in a day - it works, code is sent. But all other times - it does not send a code. In 24 hours when I try again - same thing. First time the code is sent out - the rest is not. There are no error messages as far as I can tell.

Here is my component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Icon from "@/components/common/Icon.vue";
import {
  Authenticator, AuthenticatorSignUpFormFields,
  useAuthenticator,
  AmplifyCheckBox,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-vue";
import "@aws-amplify/ui-vue/styles.css";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
import { ref, toRefs } from "vue";

import awsconfig from "@/aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const { validationErrors } = toRefs(useAuthenticator());

const services = {
  async validateCustomSignUp(formData: any) {
    if (!formData.acknowledgement) {
      return {
        acknowledgement: 'I agree to the Terms & Conditions. By signing up to create an account, I accept Curiouser AI’s Terms of Use and Privacy Policy',
      };
    }
  },
};


const formFields = {
  signIn: {
    username: {
      placeholder: 'name@email.com',
      isRequired: true,
      label: 'Email:',
      labelHidden: true,
      order: 1
    },
    password: {
      labelHidden: true,
      placeholder: 'password',
      isRequired: true,
      order: 2
    },
  },
  signUp: {
    email: {
      placeholder: 'name@email.com',
      isRequired: true,
      label: 'Email:',
      labelHidden: true,
      order: 1
    },
    password: {
      labelHidden: true,
      placeholder: 'password',
      isRequired: true,
      order: 2
    },
    confirm_password: {
      labelHidden: true,
      placeholder: 'confirm password',
      isRequired: true,
      order: 3
    },
  },
}

</script>

<template>
  <div class="container-signup" >
  <Authenticator class="authentication background-img"
    :form-fields="formFields">
    <template v-slot:sign-up-fields>
      <icon class="signupTracker1" name="signupTracker1" />
      <h2 class="createAccount"> Create your account </h2>
      <p class="recommend">we recommend using your work email</p>
      <authenticator-sign-up-form-fields />

      <amplify-check-box :errorMessage="validationErrors.acknowledgement" />
      <p class="acceptTerms"> By signing up to create an account, I accept Curiouser AI's <span class="span">Terms of Use </span> and <span class="span">Privacy Policy</span></p>
      
    </template>

    <template v-slot:confirm-sign-up-header>
      <icon class="signupTracker1" name="signupTracker2" />
      <h2 class="createAccount"> Verify your email</h2>
    </template>

    <template v-slot="{ user, signOut }">
      <Header @signout="signOut()" :username="user.attributes['preferred_username']" />
      <RouterView />
    </template>
    <template v-slot:sign-in-header>
      <h2
        class="signinAccount">
        Sign in to your account
      </h2>
    </template>
  </Authenticator>
</div>
</template>
```

I need the code to be sent out every time. The signIn amplify component is also just imported so I dont have the ability to see the actual code for it.

Comment: the frontend look healthy. 
did you checked the Email settings for Amazon Cognito user pools ? (amplify auth)